# Use html5Mode true in AngularJS with Django

Tags: django, angularjs

I'm using an `AngularJS` app with `Django Rest Framework`. However, I've setup my project such that the Angular page is served from within the `templates` folder of my setup such that

```
url(r'^$', index)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

I'm running the angular app on `/` url of Django and have setup my `ngRoutes` as follows:

```
var sgApp = angular.module('sgApp', [
        'ngRoute',
    ]);

sgApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

However, when I try to access an invalid url such as `localhost:8000/some-random-url`, it'll redirect to Django's inbuilt `404` page. Is there a way for me to fix this? Or do I have to completely abstract the angular app from the rest framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add in your angularjs router, the default route value (`otherwhise`)

```
sgApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

Then add this to the bottom of your `urls.py`

```
url(r'^.*$', index),
```

This means that if requested url did not match any previous url rules, redirect to `index`. Notice `*` in `^.*$`

Comment: Hey, how do I make API calls work now that `html5mode` is present? Whenever I try to make any api calls, it returns to the `'/'` url present in the `$routeProvider`

Comment: @Newtt Are u making those api calls using  $http ? or just broswer?

Comment: @Newtt you need to place `url(r'^.*$', index)` at bottom of your `urls.py`.It should be the last rule in your `urls.py`.

Comment: Oh yeah! I ended up placing another url after that. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: how about if you want it to stay on the given url? for example the url visited was /orders what should I do so if the user refreshes it the page stays at /orders and not gets redirected back to the index? @levi

Comment: I have the `url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),` line at the end of the urls, but the api is not being hit. Any ideas what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

With Django/ DRF, for a series of routes have the index route with the `.*$` as the last:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('agents.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('utils.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('authentication.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^accounts/login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
handler404 = 'views.handle_page_not_found_404'
```

where index is the last route.